# Add smooth transition effect on menu toggle (Twenty Fourteen WordPress Theme)

Tags: wordpress, menu, toggle, transition, slide

I'm using the WordPress twenty fourteen theme. Whenever the browser is re-sized to mobile view, automatically, the menu toggles up. So you have to click the toggle menu and the menu should slide down.

I want to make a smooth slide down transition to the menu whenever I click the menu toggle. By default the theme don't have any transition effect. I inserted some transition effect but it doesn't work. Is it possible for me to do it by CSS only? If yes how?

Do I need to work with the jQuery to solve this problem.

I am working with this website http://ash-malon.info/

Some of the code I inserted transitions, only the padding ease is working, I want the total ease effect when ever it slides down or up.

```
.primary-navigation {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
    box-sizing:         border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 24px;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}


.primary-navigation.toggled-on {
    padding: 72px 0 36px;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use jQuery since you've been already using a functions.js

I believe you want to apply the same effect with jquery slideToggle.

Here's a good example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stbV7/)

You can [click here](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) for more information about slideToggle.

You can replace the toggle JS you've added to the code below in your functions.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
        $('.menu-main-menu-container').slideToggle('slow');
    });
 });
```

And also you can remove `transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;` on your CSS.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Awesome Jed! ;-D you're a lifesaver.